# IIS express suddenly not displaying web page

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

Perhaps someone can help me figure out what's going on.

I'm running VS 2013 and working on a Web Forms application (not an MVC app). I'm using the templates that came down, including all the cool FriendlyUrls functionality. I've been working on this website for several weeks without any problem.

Today, for no apparent reason, one of my pages stopped working. When I attempted to view it, I got an error message that the server was not configured to list directories. My web page does not attempt to list the contents of any directory. It just has some images and some relatively simple Javascript (which does not attempt to enumerate anything).

The error message suggested I run the following command in the IIS Express directory:

```
appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true
```

Just for the sake of experimenting, I ran that command. Now when I attempt to view the page, I get something that looks like this (the page is named Menus.aspx)

### localhost - /Menus/

### [To Parent Directory]

Clicking on "To Parent Directory" takes me to the home page, as one might expect.

I created a new page, Menus2.aspx, and copied all of the code from Menus.aspx into Menus2.aspx, and Menus2 runs fine.  In addition, when I upload the site to Azure, Menus works correctly (as does Menus2). So I think my code is innocent of any wrongdoing.

I then deleted Menus.aspx and renamed Menus2.aspx to Menus.aspx, and I'm back to the same problem.

I was working in a git branch, and reverted back to master to see if at least my original configuration would work, but now even in master I can't get the page to come up.

So it looks like the problem is that something got jacked up in my local configuration, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is. I have exited VS and rebooted the machine in hopes that the problem will disappear as mysteriously as it started, but no luck.

Every other page in the site (6 so far) works fine. It's just this one, with this name.

So my options at this point are to simply not have a page named Menus.aspx in my project because the name has somehow become cursed, or do all of my testing by uploading to the server and seeing how it works up there, which is a pain and should not be necessary.

Can someone suggest how and where I should start looking for what happened here? This isn't the problem I expected to be working on today.

Thanks in advance.

-Rob

Comment: What URL are you accessing? Do you have a default page? There's a lot of information here but I'm not sure much of it is relevant.

Comment: I am in Visual Studio, and am accessing the page via "View Page in Browser. The resultant URL is http://localhost:60895/Menus/. The default page works fine. All other pages in the site work like they are supposed to. I have tried running the site via good old F5 also, and everything works fine until I navigate to the Menus page, at which time I get the thing above.